# How to get first date of the month till the current date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Can anyone please let me know how to get the list of the first date of the month till the current date of the same month?lets say i want to get the first date of May 2015 till 17th May 2015.

the format should be like this : ddmmyyyy

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "list". Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: list meaning the result will display the the first date till the current date with year and month sideways

e.g.
date - month - year
01-05-2015
02-05-2015
.....
.....
...till the current date 17-05-2015

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1297)

To get the days of the month from the start to the current day:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) + LEVEL - 1 AS DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EXTRACT( DAY FROM SYSDATE )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1297/0)**:

```
| DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH |
|-----------------------|
| May, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
|           .           |
|           .           |
|           .           |
| May, 15 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 16 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 17 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH CTE( DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH, Lvl ) AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1
  FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) + Lvl, Lvl + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Lvl < EXTRACT( DAY FROM SYSDATE )
)
SELECT DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH FROM CTE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1297/1)**:

```
| DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH |
|-----------------------|
| May, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
|           .           |
|           .           |
|           .           |
| May, 15 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 16 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 17 2015 00:00:00 |
```

To get all days of the month:

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) + LEVEL - 1 AS DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EXTRACT( DAY FROM LAST_DAY( SYSDATE ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1297/2)**:

```
| DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH |
|-----------------------|
| May, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
|           .           |
|           .           |
|           .           |
| May, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 31 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
WITH CTE( DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH, Lvl ) AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1
  FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) + Lvl, Lvl + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Lvl < EXTRACT( DAY FROM LAST_DAY( SYSDATE ) )
)
SELECT DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH FROM CTE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1297/3)**:

```
| DATE_OF_CURRENT_MONTH |
|-----------------------|
| May, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
|           .           |
|           .           |
|           .           |
| May, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
| May, 31 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `connect by` the `level` pseudo column and format this result by concatinating it to the current month and year:

```
SELECT     TO_CHAR(LEVEL, '09') || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'mmyyyy')
FROM       dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd'))
```

EDIT:
To display all the days in the month, you could use the [`last_day`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm) function to check the number of days in the month:

```
SELECT     TO_CHAR(LEVEL, '09') || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'mmyyyy')
FROM       dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), 'dd'))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.i will try this out tomorrow at work and let you know if it worked. :)

Comment: i just ran the query on SQL fiddle and i exactly got what i needed.if i want to see more dates of the current month,what should i do then?i mean the dates after 17th of may.

thank you.

Comment: @Iftekhar You can change the condition in the `connect by` clause

Comment: Mureinik,how do i change that?would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Iftekhar What is the exact requirement? To show all the days in May?

Comment: yeah all the dates in may

Comment: @Iftekhar I've edited my answer with the solution - see there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mureinik.i got all the dates of the current month now.